# How to catch element and all its subelements fully rendered event

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

About one day I'm trying to figure out how to catch event of html element fully loaded and **rendered**.

I tried probably almost everything, from binding on load, ready, etc. So far I just came to state that I catch an event when html is visible on page but, not fully rendered.

What "fully rendered" mean? I have a `<div>` which contains a table filed from controllers' variables. There is some text in these variables. When this text is too long, my `<div>` element grows in height when the text appear in a `<div>`. And based on this divs' height I set another elements fixed position.
Basically, I want to catch moment, when particular `<div>` let say with `id="myDiv"` is shown with all of its' content and it will not change from that time, so I can use information about its' size and position for further use.

Is it somehow possible to catch an event when `<div>` and all its' subelements are fully rendered on page?

**Note:** My `<div>` is placed in partial html loaded by `<div ui-view></div>` in another html file.

Answer (score -1):

You can used `setTimeout` method after your `div` content load like as below

```
$("document").ready(function() {
    setTimeout(function() {
        $("ul.galleria li:first-child img").trigger('click');
    },10);
});
```

Comment: OH REALLY?!! Copy-Paste someones' else code related to totally different problem? You wouldn't believe but it really does not work. As I said in my question, I tried almost all variations of ready. `Ready` does not solve anything. `setTimeout` occupies CPU and everything is waiting, and does not work either.